# AMPscript / SSJS learning resources

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, learning

I'm fairly new to using AMPscript and SSJS and am looking to use both in future email campaigns.  However, I'm having a very hard time finding any learning resources outside of the SFMC documentation.

Can anyone suggest any sites/blogs/documents to help a beginner better understand AMPscript and SSJS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It'd be great if the documentation was better. Unfortunately, there a very few resources outside of the SF ecosystem.

IMO, you've found the best resource -- the [**marketing-cloud**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud),  [**ampscript**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) and [**SSJS**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssjs) tags and the helpful community here on SFSE.

Most AMPScript topics have been discussed and re-discussed.  The powerful **[SFSE search](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/searching)** can help you find some help right away.

Here's what I recommend for learning **AMPScript**:

- [The AMPscript Guide](http://ampscript.guide/)
- [AMPScript Syntax Guide](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/)
- [AMPScript Personalization Strings](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/)
- [AMPscript Function Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/functions.htm)
- [SFMC Developers Group on Github](https://github.com/sfmcdg) (recipes, recordings from past presentations, etc.)

And for **Server-side JavaScript**:

- [SSJS Syntax Guide](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/)
- [SSJS API Functions](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/platform_server_side_javascript_functions/accessing_api_functions_using_the_function_object/)
- [SSJS Data Extension Functions](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/)
- [SFMC Custom Preference Center Boilerplate](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8)

I've written about several common SFMC topics (AMPScript, SSJS, etc.) on my personal blog.  I use these things frequently in my day-to-day work:

- [SFMC on sprignaturemoves.com](http://sprignaturemoves.com/category/salesforce-marketing-cloud/)
- [My SFMC Gists on Github](https://gist.github.com/wvpv)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much for this!  All I've wanted was just a nudge in the right direction, so this is perfect.  Cheers!

Comment: For additional have a look here https://github.com/mattcam/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes

Answer (score 1):

Adam's links are quite cool for AMPScript but I'd like to add [SFMC Cookbook](https://github.com/JoernBerkefeld/SFMC-Cookbook) as a resource that focuses on **SSJS** mostly. Hope it helps