# SSJS extension function call to append variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, actionfunction, ssjs, landing-page

I have one line in my could that's giving me a 500 internal err and it's my append to the dropdown list. I've tried  `$('#test').append(fillDataList(obj)); and jQuery('#test').append(fillDataList(obj));`

```
<html>
<head>

<script runat="server">   
 Platform.Load('Core','1');
</script>
</head>
<body>
  Test Dropbox 8
<select id="test"></select>


</body>
</html>

  <script runat="server"> 
    var fillDataList = function( options )
{
      var items = '';
        $.each( options, function ( index, option ) {
            items += '<option value="' + option + '">'
            items += option
            items += '</option>'
            });
            return items
 };

var obj = { one: 'hey 1', two: 'hey 2', three: 'hey 3', four: 'hey 4', five: 'hey 5'};

  $('#test').append(fillDataList(obj));

</script>
```

Comment: The SFMC _server-side_  JavaScript runs _before_ the page loads, so keep that in mind.  Looks like you're mixing client-side jQuery and SSJS.  That won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Would you be able to point me in the right direction to getting this to work as ssjs. i haven't been able to find any examples that helps me understand. I'm a visual person I need to see some form of example to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I've accomplished something similar in SSJS.  The idea is that you build the Select HTML in a SSJS block and output it in the body of the page.

```
<script runat="server">

  Platform.Load('Core','1.1.1');

  var MONTHNAMES = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var monthSelect = "<select>";
  monthSelect += "<option value=''>Select Month</option>";

  for (var i = 0; i < MONTHNAMES.length; i++) {
     monthSelect += "<option value='"+MONTHNAMES[i]+"'>" +MONTHNAMES[i]+ "</option>";
  }

  monthSelect += "</select>";

</script><html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

Month: <ctrl:eval>monthSelect</ctrl:eval>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image: month select]

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much. Can you please explain <ctrl:eval> I came across this in the MC docs but didn't quit understand it

Comment: Most of the good SSJS stuff is outlined on the [**SSJS Syntax Guide**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/) wiki page.

Comment: Also, this answer has a good overview of the resources: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/130337/5202

Comment: What if I want to replace the var MONTHNAME to equal an html page content. I tried %%[ set @JSON = HttpGET("insert URL here") ]%% but when printed out come out all garbaly goop. instead of the content on that json page which is [ " Child and Youth Worker ", " Energy Systems Engineering Technology ", " Digital Photography ",]; –